# Find the roots of $z^3 +3z^2 +3z +3=0$

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers, roots, cubics

Hello I have this problem:

Find all $z \in C$

$z^3 +3z^2 +3z +3=0.$

With Mathematica I get 3 roots

$z_1 = -1 -\sqrt[3]{2}$

$z_2 = -1 + (1 + i \sqrt{3})/2^{(2/3)}$

$z_3 = -1 + (1 - i \sqrt{3})/2^{(2/3)}$

But I don't know how can find this roots.  Also I don't know to reduce this cubic equation  to a quadratic equation

How do you solve this?

Any help will be appreciated

Thanks you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note that$$z^3+3z^2+3z+3=0\iff(z+1)^3=-2.$$Can you take it from here?

Comment: Thank you very much @José Carlos Santos  I try to find the roots from $(z+1)^3=-2.$ but I couldn't

Comment: The cubic roots of $-2$ are $-\sqrt[3]2$, $\sqrt[3]2\left(\frac{\sqrt3}2+\frac i2\right)$, and $\sqrt[3]2\left(\frac{\sqrt3}2-\frac i2\right)$. So, the roots of $(z+1)^3=-2$ are those three numbers minus $1$.

Comment: Thank you very much @José Carlos Santos

Comment: I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Now that you know the roots, it’s easy to express the cubic as the product of linear and quadratic terms. The cubic is just $(z-z_1)(z-z_2)(z-z_3)$, and the second two factors combine to give you a quadratic.

If you don’t already have the roots (which would be the usual situation), you have to use a bit of creativity, as in the answer from José, or you have to use one of the [cubic roots formulae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation).

Comment: Well, when solving a cubic, you introduce a quadratic equation to help find the roots of the cubic. You are not supposed to use the roots to find the quadratic to... find the roots. :) If that's what he means by "reduce this cubic to a quadratic".

Answer (score 0):

To solve a cubic of the form $z^3+bz^2+cz+d=0$, you can make the substitution $y=z+b/3$ to get a cubic in $y$ where the coefficient of $y^2$ is zero; this is known as a "depressed cubic". To solve a depressed cubic equation, you would usually make another substitution (e.g [Vieta's substitution](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/VietasSubstitution.html)), which leaves you with a quadratic equation. However, in this case it is even simpler: by setting $y=z+1$, we see that
$$
(y-1)^3+3(y-1)^2+3(y-1)+3=y^3+2=0 \, .
$$
Hence, $y$ equals one of the three cube roots of $-2$, and so $z$ equals $-1$ plus one of the cube roots of $-2$.